# apacite: change ampersand (&) to comma between the last and second last names

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am new to `biblatex`. I am using the package `apacite` for formatting references in APA format. I come up with a list of names that looks like: `Ghosh, M & Razmpour, A`. How can change the `&` between the last name and the second last name  to a  comma?

Comment: bibtex and biblatex are not the same. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: AS a new user I am not allowed to post images.

Comment: But you're allowed to post code snippets. Anyway, I hope Mico's solution is working for you.

Comment: The APA style puts an '&' between the final two names in a list of book authors (when there are less than seven authors) because that is required by the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association* (section 4.16 in the 5th edition, 2001). If you don't want that then you might want to look for a style that better matches your requirement or that of your publisher(s).

Answer (score 3):

Just issue the following command in your document's preamble (but after the `\usepackage{apacite}` instruction:

```
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{"and"}
```

Check also page 27 of the manual for the `apacite` package.